# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference occurs when calling public sub

Tags: vb.net, public-method, object-reference

I have a Public Class "General" in which is a Public Sub "updateDynamics". When I attempt to reference it in the code-behind for a page like so:

```
updateDynamics(get_prospect.dynamicsID)
```

I get the following error:

> reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You either have to make the method `Shared` or use an instance of the class `General`:

```
Dim gen = New General()
gen.updateDynamics(get_prospect.dynamicsID)
```

or

```
General.updateDynamics(get_prospect.dynamicsID)

Public Shared Sub updateDynamics(dynID As Int32)
    ' ... '
End Sub
```

[**Shared(VB.NET)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed. I had tried doing instances, but was attempting to do an instance of updateDynamics, instead of realizing that updateDynamics would be a method of General.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Declaration of the desired object and mark it Shared.

Friend Shared WithEvents MyGridCustomer As Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX