# How do I create an object reference so that a VB.NET function with .request or .response will work in a module file?

Tags: asp.net

My vb.net module with .request or .response is causing compiler error "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

I just moved a working function with .response and .request from my ...aspx.vb form file to a new module.vb file, and now get this compiler error.

When my ..aspx.vb code calls the new function with the .response & .request in the module does it need to pass an object reference somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference occurs when calling public sub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462479/reference-to-a-non-shared-member-requires-an-object-reference-occurs-when-callin)

Comment: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request` and `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response`, you have to add reference to `System.Web` to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Shadow Wizard.  That was correct answer:

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request 
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response