# Call a sub on another form in classLibrary project

Tags: vb.net

I have a solution with multiple-project, and i have a master form called `master_ChartofAccount`, and on `coa_Create` after saving the data, i want to call a `Sub` named `showCoa` to refresh a grid on `coa_Create`, here's my code :

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdAdd.Click
    Dim frm As New coa_Create
    frm.ShowDialog(Me)
End Sub
```

and here's `cmdSave` code on `coa_Create` :

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    If Not allowSave() Then Exit Sub
    Dim str As String
    txtKode.Tag = IIf(IsNothing(txtKode.Tag), "", txtKode.Tag)

    If txtKode.Tag.ToString = "" Then
        str = "insert into t_chart_of_account (coa_code, coa_name, p_code, is_parent, db_cr, bs_is) " _
            & "values ('" & objComp.clearSingleQuote(txtKode.Text) & "', '" & objComp.clearSingleQuote(txtNama.Text) & "', " _
            & "'" & objComp.clearSingleQuote(txtParentCode.Text) & "', " & IIf(chkParent.Checked = True, 1, 0) & ", " _
            & "'" & IIf(optDb.Checked = True, "DR", "CR") & "', '" & IIf(optBS.Checked = True, "BS", "IS") & "')"
    Else
        str = "update t_chart_of_account set coa_code = '" & txtKode.Text & "', " _
            & "coa_name = '" & objComp.clearSingleQuote(txtNama.Text) & "', p_code = '" & txtParentCode.Text & "', " _
            & "is_parent = " & IIf(chkParent.Checked = True, 1, 0) & ", db_cr = '" & IIf(optDb.Checked = True, "DR", "CR") & "', " _
            & "bs_is = '" & IIf(optBS.Checked = True, "BS", "IS") & "' WHERE id = " & txtKode.Tag.ToString
    End If
    objComp.setExecute(str, False)

    master_ChartofAccount.showCoa() 'error on this line : Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

    objComp.msgShow(Me, "Data berhasil di simpan.", "Simpan Berhasil", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    cmdClose_Click(sender, e)
 End Sub
```

why there's an error msg :

> Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

on `master_ChartofAccount.showCoa()`

how to fix this ?
is there other way to call a `Sub` from another `Form`?

i tried :

```
Dim frm as new master_ChartofAccount
frm.showCoa()
```

but the grid on `master_ChartofAccount` won't refresh.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference occurs when calling public sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462479/reference-to-a-non-shared-member-requires-an-object-reference-occurs-when-callin)

Comment: pass your master_chartofAccount form to your coa_Create form

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b In fact, this is already done with `frm.ShowDialog(Me)`. You can access it with `Me.Owner` on `coa_Create`

Comment: Then you should cast the parent of coa_Create to the class type of master_chartofAccount

Answer (score 0):

Inside coa_Create, declare a property of master_ChartofAccount form type.

```
Public Property Master_ChartofAccount As <class name for your master_chartofaccount form>
```

Then in cmdAdd_Click

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdAdd.Click
    Dim frm As New coa_Create
    frm.Master_ChartofAccount = Me
    frm.ShowDialog(Me)
End Sub
```

And in your cmdSave_Click

```
Me.MasterChartofAccount.showCoa()
```

OR

inside cmdSave_Click, just cast the parent to the class type of mast_chartofaccount

```
CType(Me.Parent, <class name of master chart of account>).showCoa()
```