# "TripleDES.CreateEncryptor() "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

Tags: sql, vb.net

I Import the `Imports System.Security.Cryptography` to encrypt my password but using this and adding this code.

```
Public Function EncryptData(ByVal plaintext As String) As String
    Dim plainttextBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext)
    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms, TripleDES.CreateEncryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    encStream.Write(plainttextBytes, 0, plainttextBytes.Length)
    encStream.FlushFinalBlock()

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)

End Function
```

I'm having a error `Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference`. Can someone help me. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference occurs when calling public sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462479/reference-to-a-non-shared-member-requires-an-object-reference-occurs-when-callin)

Answer (score 1):

`CreateEncryptor` is an instance method, not `Shared`, so you need to call it on an instance of the `TripleDES` class, not on the class itself. What you're doing would be akin to this:

```vb
Return Convert.ToBase64String(MemoryStream.ToArray)
```

You are obviously calling `ToArray` on an instance of the `MemoryStream` class rather than on the class itself. You need to do the same for the `TripleDES.CreateEncryptor` method, i.e. create an instance of the class first and then call the method on that.